# fire HTML on change event with Loop through array vaiable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I pass an array variable from PHP to JavaScript.
My variable content in JavaScript console is:

```
[
  {
    "function": "change",
    "parameter": "link",
    "err_msg": "It seems your input is not valid",
    "id": "element1"
  },
  {
    "function": "change",
    "parameter": "check",
    "err_msg": "please enter a valid input",
    "id": "element2"
  }
]
```

I want to know is this possible to use this variable to fire JavaScript/jquery on change event for element1 and element2 elements?

I use following codes for this but not works.

```
jQuery.each( passed_variable, function( key, element ) {
    jQuery( '#'  + element.id + '-source' ).on( element.function, function() {
        switch ( element.parameter ) {
            case 'link' :
                reg_match = new RegExp('^<.* rel=("|\').*("|\') .*href=("|\').*("|\').*>$');
                if ( ! reg_match.test(element.value) ) {
                    this.setCustomValidity( validation.err_msg );
                    this.reportValidity();
                } else {
                    this.setCustomValidity('');
                }
        }               
    });
});
```

Comment: Need your HTML. The terms used like: *"change"*,  and *"check"* as well as methods like `.setCustomValidity()` allude to using `<form>`, whilst the term *"link"* suggests that you are using `<a>` as well?

Comment: Please provide sample html as per [mre]

Comment: If you receive this 'variable' from PHP as a ```string```, you might need to parse it with ```JSON.parse()```

Comment: thanks to [Kinglish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1772933/kinglish) help, i fix my problem. my problem was on another line in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reconstructed this into a snippet and it works fine.. which leads me to think that you're getting the `passed_variable` data back as ajax and not setting it correctly.

Get data from PHP -> assign it a variable -> send that variable into a function that contains your logic

```js
function applyNewData(passed_variable) {
  jQuery.each(passed_variable, function(key, element) {
    jQuery('#' + element.id + '-source').on(element.function, function() {
      console.log('Fired!')
      switch (element.parameter) {
        case 'link':
          reg_match = new RegExp('^<.* rel=("|\').*("|\') .*href=("|\').*("|\').*>$');
          if (!reg_match.test(element.value)) {
            //this.setCustomValidity( validation.err_msg );
            //this.reportValidity();
          } else {
            //this.setCustomValidity('');
          }
      }
    });
  });
}

const incoming_data = [{
    "function": "click",
    "parameter": "link",
    "err_msg": "It seems your input is not valid",
    "id": "element1"
  },
  {
    "function": "change",
    "parameter": "check",
    "err_msg": "please enter a valid input",
    "id": "element2"
  }
];

applyNewData(incoming_data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='element1-source'>el 1 - on click</div>
<select id='element2-source'>
  <option>option 1 - on change</option>
  <option>option 2 - on change</option>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your time. i check my codes again.

Comment: Also, if you are getting the data back from ajax as a JSON string, you'll need to parse it. `incoming_data=JSON.parse(incoming_data);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Getting the ID could be done with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "function": "change",
    "parameter": "link",
    "err_msg": "It seems your input is not valid",
    "id": "element1"
  },
  {
    "function": "change",
    "parameter": "check",
    "err_msg": "please enter a valid input",
    "id": "element2"
  }
];

arr.map((element) => {
  //console.log(element);
  let dom_element = document.getElementById(`${element.id}-source`);
  //console.log(dom_element);
  dom_element.addEventListener(element.function, function(e) {
    //console.log(e)
    switch ( element.parameter ) {
        case 'link' :
          console.log('link');
          reg_match = new RegExp('^<.* rel=("|\').*("|\') .*href=("|\').*("|\').*>$');
          if ( ! reg_match.test(element.value) ) {
            //this.setCustomValidity( validation.err_msg );
            //this.reportValidity();
          }else {
            //this.setCustomValidity('');
          }
          break;
        case 'check':
          console.log('check');
          break;
    }        
})
});
```

```html
<input id="element1-source" type="text" placeholder="link">
<input id="element2-source" type="text" placeholder="check">
```